# It is possible to get the drum progression only by listening?

Tags: drums, ear-training, songwriting

I want to get the drum progression from this
[song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svoqrfmrud4) on youtube at the minute 3:24, but I am unable to get the things very clearly, I can hear a Hi Tom on it, but no much more?
It is possible to get the drum progression only by listening?

Comment: I would say yes it is possible, but because it is very quite in parts, you'll have to use a bit of intuition as well your ears.

Comment: Sounds like a series of flams to me, going round the drums.

Comment: I expected this to be a trick question and that there wouldn't be no drums at us all at that point, but actually it is pretty clear.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say yes, it's quite possible. An experienced drummer could listen once, and play it back on a kit almost perfectly. Available these days are means to slow down recordings, which will help you to do the hard work that experience takes. Bring it down to the speed at which you can hear every single hit, still in time, and work from there.